# Use results of CTE as a parameter for a delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an automated equipment that writes 1 timestamped line per minute in a table whenever it is no longer running a "lot" AKA production run of a product.

This equipment does not run at night, but keeps writing. I use the table in PowerBI to generate graphs and statistics and the timestamped lines that happen during the night cause issues with calculations.

I usually remove them by hand, but I would like to automate this process.

Here's what I tried thus far. This is something I'd setup to run automatically every day at 8 or so.

Eventually I’d like to automate further and have it remove any production shift where more than 400 lines are found

```
declare @Min_id as int;

with CTE as (
  select
    id
    , cast(StartTime as time) as Time
  from ChangeoverTime 
  where StartTime >= (dateadd(day, 0, cast(getdate() as date)))
)
select top 1 @Min_id
from CTE
where Time < '07:45:00'
order by Time asc;

declare @Max_id as int;

with CTE as (
  select
    id
    , cast(StartTime as time) as Time
  from ChangeoverTime 
  where StartTime >= (dateadd(day, 0, cast(getdate() as date)))
)
select top 1 @Max_id
from CTE
where Time < '07:45:00'
order by Time desc;

Delete
from ChangeoverTime
where id
between @Min_id AND @Max_id;
```

The problem with this is that I cannot seem to find a way to SET my variables using this technique. By having SET work, I could change my last select statement by a delete and I'd be  happy.

Comment: `select top 1 @var = Id ...`

Comment: Btw layout is important, it's very hard a read a query all on one line. Also the semi-colon us a statement terminator,  it a begininator

Comment: You realize that the `in (@Min_id, @Max_id)` will select/delete those two only, not anything in between? You also seem to be assuming that the `id`s are sequential and increasing, which they may or may not be? If you want to delete the night's data, why not `delete ... where Time < '07:45:00'`?

Comment: @DaleK, a begininator, ha! I never heard that word before I came to Springfield!

Comment: @GSerg no I did not, I will use BETWEEN `@Min_id AND @Max_id` then. I cannot use your `Delete time` suggestion as there is no such column I only have datetime, hence the CTE

Comment: @Icbd So? `delete from ChangeoverTime where StartTime between cast(getdate() as date) and dateadd(mi, 45, dateadd(hh, 7, cast(getdate() as date)))`? Or with any other way of constructing the "to" and "from"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DaleK

I got your suggestion to work, final query looks like this:

```
/*Here I set max minutes that I want to keep*/
Declare @Max_minutes as int
Set @Max_minutes = 400

/*Looking for first ID of previous day's day shift*/
Declare @Min_id_jour as int;
with CTE AS (
    select 
        id
        , cast(StartTime as time) AS Time 
        from ChangeoverTime 
        where StartTime >= (DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))) AND StartTime < (DATEADD(day, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
        )
select top 1 @Min_id_jour = id
from CTE 
where Time > '07:45:00' 
order by Time asc;

/*Last id from previous day's day shift*/
Declare @Max_id_jour as int;
with CTE AS (
    select 
        id
        , cast(StartTime as time) AS Time 
        from ChangeoverTime 
        where StartTime >= (DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))) AND StartTime < (DATEADD(day, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
        )
select top 1 @Max_id_jour = id 
from CTE 
where Time < '15:45:00' 
order by Time desc

/*Number of minutes recorded*/
Declare @Nombre_minutes_jour as int
Set @Nombre_minutes_jour = @Max_id_jour - @Min_id_jour

/*If number of minutes is over max, delete records*/
IF @Nombre_minutes_jour > @Max_minutes
delete from ChangeoverTime 
where id between @Min_id_jour and @Max_id_jour

 /*First id of previous day's evening shift*/
Declare @Min_id_soir as int;
with CTE AS (
    select 
        id
        , cast(StartTime as time) AS Time 
        from ChangeoverTime 
        where StartTime >= (DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))) AND StartTime < (DATEADD(day, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
        )
select top 1 @Min_id_soir = id
from CTE 
where Time > '15:45:00' 
order by Time asc

/*Last id of previous day's evening shift*/
Declare @Max_id_soir as int;
with CTE AS (
    select 
        id
        , cast(StartTime as time) AS Time 
        from ChangeoverTime 
        where StartTime >= (DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))) AND StartTime < (DATEADD(day, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
        )
select top 1 @Max_id_soir = id 
from CTE 
where Time < '23:15:00' 
order by Time desc

/*How many minutes were recorded*/
Declare @Nombre_minutes_soir as int
Set @Nombre_minutes_soir = @Max_id_soir - @Min_id_soir

IF @Nombre_minutes_soir > @Max_minutes
delete from ChangeoverTime 
where id between @Min_id_soir and @Max_id_soir

/*First id of previous day's night shift (23h15)*/
Declare @Min_id_veille as int;
with CTE AS (
    select 
        id
        , cast(StartTime as time) AS Time 
        from ChangeoverTime 
        where StartTime >= (DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))) AND StartTime < (DATEADD(day, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
        )
select top 1 @Min_id_veille = id
from CTE 
where Time > '23:14:59' 
order by Time asc


/*Last id of previous day's night shift*/
Declare @Max_id_nuit as int;
with CTE AS (
    select 
        id
        , cast(StartTime as time) AS Time 
        from ChangeoverTime 
        where StartTime >= (DATEADD(day, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
        )
select top 1 @Max_id_nuit = id
from CTE 
where Time < '07:45:00' 
order by Time desc

/*How many minutes*/
Declare @Nombre_minutes_nuit as int
Set @Nombre_minutes_nuit = @Max_id_nuit - @Min_id_veille

/*If over max, delete*/
IF @Nombre_minutes_nuit > @Max_minutes
delete from ChangeoverTime 
where id between @Min_id_veille and @Max_id_nuit
```

Comment: Still terrible layout though. See my edits to your question.

Comment: Hello, Icbd! Thank you for your question and answer. Maybe I am wrong, but your answer doesn't answer the question, and this is misleading. Please, improve your answer at least in this aspect. DaleK suggests other expected improvements, in reference to the general layout (oneliners are really, really hard to read), and to semicolons before the WITH (it's not correct, it's a superstition). Take this three comments into account, and your answer become pretty good.

Comment: @Dale K, I’ll review it further as I made more changes to automate it further. I’m not a regular user at all so forgive my formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to delete from a table by using a common table expression. Consider:

```
DECLARE @TargetTable TABLE (ID BIGINT IDENTITY, Date DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @TargetTable (Date)
SELECT TOP 100 DATEADD(MINUTE,-ROUND(((20160 - 1) * Rnd1 + 1),0),GETUTCDATE())
  FROM (VALUES (RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1)), (RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1))))) a (Rnd1, Rnd2)
    CROSS APPLY sys.sysobjects z
    CROSS APPLY sys.sysobjects y
```

This sets up a table variable and populates it with some randomly selected `DATETIME` values in the past couple of weeks.

If we look at the makeup of the table first:

```
SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE), COUNT(*)
  FROM @TargetTable
 GROUP BY CAST(Date AS DATE) WITH ROLLUP
```

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-23 | 1 |
| 2023-05-24 | 7 |
| 2023-05-25 | 8 |
| 2023-05-26 | 8 |
| 2023-05-27 | 6 |
| 2023-05-28 | 5 |
| 2023-05-29 | 10 |
| 2023-05-30 | 7 |
| 2023-05-31 | 6 |
| 2023-06-01 | 7 |
| 2023-06-02 | 5 |
| 2023-06-03 | 5 |
| 2023-06-04 | 10 |
| 2023-06-05 | 10 |
| 2023-06-06 | 5 |
| NULL | 100 |

If we then go ahead and perform the `CTE DELETE` and then check the makeup again:

```
;WITH ToDelete AS (
SELECT *
  FROM @TargetTable
 WHERE Date < DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETUTCDATE())
)

DELETE 
  FROM ToDelete

SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE), COUNT(*)
  FROM @TargetTable
 GROUP BY CAST(Date AS DATE) WITH ROLLUP
```

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-30 | 1 |
| 2023-05-31 | 6 |
| 2023-06-01 | 7 |
| 2023-06-02 | 5 |
| 2023-06-03 | 5 |
| 2023-06-04 | 10 |
| 2023-06-05 | 10 |
| 2023-06-06 | 5 |
| NULL | 49 |

The delete operates on the rows returned from the `CTE` and affects the underlying table.

Comment: You're into begininators too?

Comment: It always works that way 

Comment: It's not the intended use though. All SQL statements should be semi-colon terminated - then you don't need weird behaviour for special cases.

Comment: @PatrickHurst `;if @SyntaxOkay = 1 ;with ... ;;` always works?

Comment: @DaleK you're right, they should. But the fact of the matter is they aren't, especially when your demo code may be pasted into someone else's code. Prefixing `WITH` with a semi-colon helps to make it portable and prevent confusing situations for folks who may be less familiar with the syntax.